# Google Tag manager Android V4 Google Analytics is not updating

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am struggling to figure out a solution to integrate Google Analytics from GTM Android V4 .

I'am able to fetch/read container values from server.
My Log showing as

```
V/GoogleTagManager: putHit called
V/GoogleTagManager: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: ul=en-gb,  ht=1447672218276,  sr=720x1280,  a=818715426,  aid=demo.seneca.com.gtmsample,  cid=5adae020-bb74-40a8-9fcf-8026f8d68e40,  av=1.0,  v=1,  adid=8ee33b1a-d08e-48e1-9dbd-0f3b9a52225b,  t=appview,  an=GTMSample,  ate=0,  tid=UA-54613562-7,  _u=.r34nL,
```

[image: My GTM Tag configuration]

[image: My GTM Variable Configuration]

My Activity - OnCreate Method

```
    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", "FirstScreen"));
```

I have added all the Google Anaytics services and Permissions for GTM.

Do I need to add any of the KEYs from the link
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd

Compile Google Play services version is 
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

Note: Google Analytics are not updating even after couple of days..

I know  that I am missing something. But I could not able to figure it...

Answer (score 0):

As its a long being not answered, I resolved my problem.

First create variables using DataLayer type variable.
Lets Say **Action**

Then create Trigger:
Type-> Custom, Fire On-> Event ->, Contains-> <*Any Defined Action*> -- Save.

Then Create Tag:
Select Product- > Google Analytics <*In my case i want to track with Google Analytics*>

TagType--> Universal Analytics

Tracking ID--> Your GA projectID

Track Type --> event

Action--> Select action which is created from variables

Fire On-> Event <*Trigger created in earlier step*>

Then save and publish your container. Then download your container binary file from version list and dump in project raw folder. Then

```
DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getDataLayer();
            dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event", "Any User interaction", "Action", <*Any Defined Action*>));
```